# c# FileSystemWatcher does not raise an event when a file is modified. It only raises the event when a file is created or deleted

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I got a problem when i use c# FileSystemWatcher. It does not raise an Changed event when a doc file is modified. It only raises the event when a doc file is created or deleted.
Note: i tested on windows 7 is ok, but window 10 is not.

My code:

public class MonitorSyncing
{
    public MonitorSyncing(string monitorPath)
    {
        this._monitorPath = monitorPath;
    }

```
private readonly string _monitorPath;

public void Monitoring()
{
    Console.WriteLine($"*** START MONITOR FOLDER: {this._monitorPath} ***");
    var fileSystemWatcherSyncFolderUserSettings = new FileSystemSafeWatcher
    {
        Path = _monitorPath,
        NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.FileName |
                       NotifyFilters.DirectoryName,
        InternalBufferSize = 24576,
    };
    fileSystemWatcherSyncFolderUserSettings.Changed += OnChanged_SyncFolderUserSetting;
    fileSystemWatcherSyncFolderUserSettings.Created += OnChanged_SyncFolderUserSetting;
    fileSystemWatcherSyncFolderUserSettings.Deleted += OnChanged_SyncFolderUserSetting;
    fileSystemWatcherSyncFolderUserSettings.Renamed += OnRenamed_SyncFolderUserSetting;
    fileSystemWatcherSyncFolderUserSettings.Error += OnError;
    fileSystemWatcherSyncFolderUserSettings.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
    fileSystemWatcherSyncFolderUserSettings.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
}

private static void OnChanged_SyncFolderUserSetting(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.ChangeType)
    {
        case WatcherChangeTypes.Created:
            Console.WriteLine($"Created file: {e.FullPath}");
            break;
        case WatcherChangeTypes.Deleted:
            Console.WriteLine($"Deleted file: {e.FullPath}");
            break;
        case WatcherChangeTypes.Changed:
            Console.WriteLine($"Change file: {e.FullPath}");
            break;
    }
}

private static void OnRenamed_SyncFolderUserSetting(object source, RenamedEventArgs e)
{
    //  Show that a file has been renamed.
    Console.WriteLine($"Renamed file '{e.OldFullPath}' to '{e.FullPath}'");
}

private static void OnError(object source, ErrorEventArgs e)
{
    //  Show that an error has been detected.
    Console.WriteLine($"Error - The FileSystemWatcher has detected an error : {e.GetException().Message}");
    //  Give more information if the error is due to an internal buffer overflow.
    if (e.GetException().GetType() == typeof(InternalBufferOverflowException))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(("Error - The file system watcher experienced an internal buffer overflow: " + e.GetException().Message));
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Hi, what have you tried so far? Can you add a snippet so we can see what you are doing?

Comment: hi Filippo Agostini, i'm just add the code on my question

Comment: Sorry but I am unable to recreate your problem: I put your exact code in a new console app, added the FileSystemSafeWatcher class and it worked almost fine. The only strange behavior that I noticed was that a double event is fired when I create a new file to the monitored folder. Only in this case it was raised first a "Created" event and after a "Deleted" event.

Comment: Did you see Change file event?

Comment: Yes....I start monitoring a folder then I created a new txt file and saved into that folder (events Created and Deleted raised). I closed my text editor, opened again the same file, added few lines and saved. It raised Change event

Comment: you can test with doc file? ex: *.docx or *.pptx

Comment: That is quite normal.  A responsible program does *not* modify a file, that can cause irrecoverable data loss when something goes wrong.  It instead creates a new file, and if that worked then it renames the files and deletes the original.  An Office program like Word certainly works that way.

Comment: @HansPassant thank you for the explanation. You are right, nlkhangit code tested with a Word file (docx) showed that Word for updating / changing the file do a lot of job creating temp files and deleting old files after renaming it and don't Update/Change directly the monitored file.

Comment: You need to add NotifyFilters.CreationTime to NotifyFilters probably.

Comment: i added NotifyFilters.CreationTime to NotifyFilters probably. it's ok on my side but other side is not.

Comment: hi Filippo Agostini. Sorry, you can add NotifyFilters.CreationTime? it's ok with you?

Comment: hi I added NotifyFilters.CreationTime and now I catch the Change event. I had a lot of create / delete / rename events only for opening a Word file without touching it.

Comment: hi Filippo Agostini, I'm just update NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.Size | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName | NotifyFilters.Security to NotifyFilters probably, then it's ok now. But i need to ignore a few events